# How to NOT scroll after notifyDataSetChanged on a RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

sometimes I'm replacing all the data from my ArrayList datasource like so:

```
private ArrayList data;

public void replaceAll(ArrayList newItems) {
    this.data.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < newItems.size(); i++) {
        this.data.set(i, newItems.get(i));
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

but if for example `this.data.size() == 50;` and `newItems.size() == 30;` and thus data changed from 50 children to 30, after I run `notifyDataSetChanged()` my RecyclerView scrolls to the next child.

(i.e if I was on position 15, it goes to 16)

This **ONLY** happens when the newData size is less than the old, and I can't figure why.

---

**p.s1:** I tried running:

```
int childCntWeLostAfterMutation = data.size() - newData.size();
notifyItemRangeChanged(0, newData.size());
notifyItemRangeRemoved(newData.size(), childCntWeLostAfterMutation);
```

but then things get worse. It scrolls a lot further behind, and it totally messes up the visible position.

**p.s2:** Please don't tell me to `smoothScrollToPosition`, it's super messy and I don't think it will work on my scenario.

**p.s3:** I am already using `setHasStableIds(true)` and my `public long getItemId(int position)` returns a unique ID for every child.

Please help!

Comment: user a List for storing your data and so you can clear and then `generalList.addAll(incomingList);`

Comment: Hi @cutiko Why would that make any difference to my problem?